# How Task.WhenAll works under the hood

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

How does `Task.WhenAll` works under the hood? Does it create separate thread which finished once all of tasks receive callback about finish. I have a suggestion, that under the hood it creates new thread and pass work to system drivers for each of the task and waits for them at the end, but not sure about is it correct or not?

Comment: I would guess it adds continuations to all the tasks and once the last one finishes the continuation will trigger the task it returns to update it's state.  There is no need for it to create a new thread.

Comment: Here's the souce code if you want to see https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/tasks/Task.cs,929d1a3d98d89901

Comment: The first thing you need to understands, are Task are not threads. Second thing, is this will all be managed and nothing to do with drivers.

Comment: @juharr Yes, you're right. Thank you

Comment: Looks like this question was closed, but I generally don’t see that the close reason makes sense. I think it’s a good and reasonable question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `Task.WhenAll` doesn't create a thread.  It is possible that some of the element tasks passed to `Task.WhenAll` have created threads (but optimally they would not).  `Task.WhenAll` itself just calls `ContinueWith` on the element tasks, passing a piece of code that checks the other task states.  There is no "wait".

---

Here is an example of how `Task.WhenAll` may be implemented.  (It is not the Microsoft code)

```
Task MyWhenAll(IEnumerable<Task> tasks)
{
    var a = tasks.ToArray();
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    Array.ForEach(a, WatchTask);
    return tcs.Task;

    async void WatchTask(Task t)
    {
        try {
            await t;
        }
        catch {}

        if (a.All(element => element.IsCompleted)) {
            if (a.Any(element => element.IsFaulted))
                // omitted logic for adding each individual exception
                // to the aggregate
                tcs.TrySetException(new AggregateException());
            else
                tcs.TrySetResult(true);
        }
    }
}
```